# sql alphanumeric with range start & end

Tags: sql, sql-server, alphanumeric

I have a problem, how to search alphanumeric with range (start & end) such as below :

[image: table]

if i use `BETWEEN`, the result will problem with the number that have letter at the end, in pic/table = Input 2.

So, how can i to get the Id 6 result when keyin HSF3145858B

pls advise

Thank You

Comment: What database (mysql, postgres, sql server...) are you using?

Comment: put your database schema and some sample data instead of image attachment

Comment: im using sql server..

Comment: $tsql = "SELECT Product FROM tbl_serial_range WHERE '$serialno' BETWEEN Start AND End"; - my current query

Comment: if im enter Input 1..the result is ok...but when im enter input 2.. the result will display Id 5 & 6...

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to add more information (and then you can indicate the code by highlighting it and hitting the `{}` button)

Answer (score 0):

That is because `between` uses alphabetical ordering. You should probably add another check to confirm that the searched code is the same length as the start and/or end. This could be done by putting parenthesis around the first clause and adding `AND (len('$serialno') = len (Start))`

This would lead to the following which should work

```
$tsql = "SELECT Product FROM tbl_serial_range WHERE ('$serialno' BETWEEN Start AND End) AND (len('$serialno') = len (Start)) ";
```